# Is it possible to know if a Telerik MVC Combobox value is a new or existing value?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, telerik

In our Asp.net MVC application we want to put in a combo box that provides several locations that users have entered previously, but also allow them to type out a new location name.  When the user enters a new location name we need to take them to another form so we can add that location to the database, if they select a pre-existing location then we need to take that location's id and tie it to the core domain entity they are editing at the time.

The problem with this is after playing with the demos at http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/combobox/api there does not seem to be a way to know if a record is new or existing.

For example, in that link if you select "The Dark Knight" from the drop down and click the get value button you get "7".  However, if you also type "7" in the drop down box you also get the value of "7".

Is there any way of knowing that I typed the number 7 in the box (and it's a new entry) as opposed to the user actually selecting the option with a value of 7?

The only way I can think of this is to check if the value is equal to the text, and if so consider it a new option, but this seems tenuous, and I have a feeling only the value will get posted back on form submission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quickest and easiest way to determine if the selected value in the Combobox is part of the original databound items is:

```
$('#movies').getKendoComboBox().dataItem()
```

If it doesn't return a dataItem (i.e. it is `undefined`) then the value does not exist in the dataSource.

You can also use:

```
$('#movies').getKendoComboBox().select()
```

Which returns `-1`.

It is also worth noting that you are not actually adding a new item to the DataSource here.

If you were, you'd be able to return a proper [ComboBox dataItem](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/combobox#methods-dataItem) and use the method `isNew` in the Model.

I would recommend you read the docs on the [Kendo DataSource](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource) and the [Model](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/model) (in particular the [isNew method](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/model#methods-isNew))